# (Finite) continued fractions over a general domain

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, commutative-algebra, continued-fractions

I am looking for some literature (articles or books) where finite continued fractions over a general integral domains (that is, in a fraction field of that domain, but the "coefficients" are from the domain) are studied. Since the main focus concerning the continued fractions is naturally on the case of $\mathbb{Z}$ (or, sometimes, $\mathbb{C}[x]$ or something similar), I was unable to find any.

Thanks in advance for any references.

Comment: Since continued fractions involve fractions, it seems like you need a field rather than an integral domain. Even then you need to worry about division by$~0$.

Comment: Of course, the intended meaning of "over a general domain" was "in a fraction field of that domain" - hence the referring to the case of $\mathbb{Z}$ and not $\mathbb{Q}$. I will clarify that.

Comment: (Moreover, it is useful to refer to the cont. fractions with respect to the domain, because the sets of continued fractions with "coefficients" in various domains with the same fraction field could be different)

Comment: It is not clear what you are interested in. Could you give an example of an integral domain$~R$ and an element of its fraction field that _cannot_ be represented as a finite continued fraction with coefficients in$~R$? Or if that is not the type of questions that interest you, what is the type of question that does interest you?

Comment: The example is any domain which is not Bézout.  My main interest, concerning the cont. fractions, is the relation to $\omega$-stage Euclidean domains (a certain generalisation of the concept of Euclidean domain; see article of G. E. Cooke [here](http://www.deepdyve.com/lp/de-gruyter/a-weakening-of-the-euclidean-property-for-integral-domains-and-qr6ap732Bh)). In the mentioned article, Cor. 3 of Prop. 6 states that a domain is $\omega$-stage iff the set of cont. fractions exhausts the fraction field. Since $\omega$-stage implies Bézout, conterexamples must exist.

Comment: (a better link for the same article [here](https://eudml.org/doc/151708))